# New fearture in react-router-dom v6 useOutletContext() issue, what versions support it

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom and react-router v6.0.2 and I want to use the useOutletContext() the new features in v6 to pass props through outlet but it return this issue.

[image]

How can't I fix it and what versions does useOutletContext() support

Answer (score 0):

The `useOutletContext` hook and `Outlet` context was a feature introduced in [v6.1.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v6.1.0).

> `<Outlet>` can now receive a context prop. This value is passed to
> child routes and is accessible via the new `useOutletContext` hook.

Uninstall the current version

```
npm uninstall -s react-router-dom
```

Either bump to this minimum version

```
npm install -s react-router-dom@6.1
```

or install the current/latest version

- ```
  npm install -s react-router-dom@6
  ```
- ```
  npm install -s react-router-dom@latest
  ```